# text box for an existing drop down

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to enable a editable text box where on entering the first two digits the values get filtered to the matching ones sort of thing for an existing drop down menu but i seem to be getting no where with that.It would be wonderful if someone could help me out with this issue.

```
    <td>
     Part Number
</td>
<td>
    <select class=\"".$klasse_ausw["aggregat_ausw_drpd"]."\" name=\"aggregat_ausw_drpd\"  style=\"width:90pt; size:1;\">
    <option value=></option>";

    $sql_aggregat_ausw3_drpd="SELECT * FROM vers_einl_aggregatnummer ORDER BY  vers_einl_aggregatnummer.aggr_nr ASC";
    $result_aggregat_ausw3_drpd=mysql_query($sql_aggregat_ausw3_drpd);
    while($row_aggregat_ausw3_drpd=mysql_fetch_array($result_aggregat_ausw3_drpd)){
extract($row_aggregat_ausw3_drpd, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "ausw3");
echo '                                                  <option value="'.$ausw3_id.'"';
if(($_POST["aggregat_ausw_drpd"]==$ausw3_id) ||               ($_GET["aggregat_ausw_drpd"]==$ausw3_id)){
    echo ' selected';
}
echo '                               >'.$ausw3_aggr_nr.'</option>';
   }
    echo "</select></td></tr>
```

Comment: I ran out of breath from reading by the 25th word due to the lack of punctuation. Where is your editable textbox?

Comment: well, that is what i wanted to know. How do i add a text box to search from the drop down and then select it

Comment: where does PHP start and HTML begin, where does the SQL begin? oh lord :|
WHEN DOES IT STOP

Comment: that said, those drop downs already jump to the first matching option if you open them and press a letter or number key on your keyboard. what's the use?

Comment: i would rather have a text field where i can enter the entire number and that showing up than the first matching option coming up

Comment: this is just the part where i need help, the rest of the file works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you're looking for a way to filter a select box.

There's a number of ways to achieve this through Javascript.

[The Select2 jquery plugin is pretty good.](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/)

Comment: this is something which i was looking for.Thanks a lot!!